# MySQL - Trouble to create a 1:1 relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I'm trying to create a 1:1 relationship at MySQL Workbench (without using Diagram). I have two tables called `agricultural_machine` and `tractor`. And I would like a relationship 1:1 being that the `agricultural_machine_id` is referenced with `tractor_id`.

### Foreign Keys at agricultural_machine table

[image]

### Foreign Keys at tractor table

[image]

### The Diagram is being formed like this

[image]

### I would like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement true 1:1 relationships you need *deferrable constraints*. That means the foreign key contraints in this case need to be ignored for a short time (probably until the end of the transaction) while you insert "the other row" in the other table. Once both rows are inserted the foreign key constraint can be reactivated and validated now. Otherwise, which row do you insert first? Any insert will fail since the FK won't be validated.

Unfortunately MySQL does not implement this *standard* SQL feature, so you won't be able to do it. You'll need to change the database to PostgreSQL or Oracle to implement 1:1 relationships.